# Windows: How does Jupyter throw a keyboard interrupt?

Tags: python, c++, jupyter-notebook, python-c-api, keyboardinterrupt

I know how to interrupt the kernel (such as by tapping `I` twice or by interrupting the kernel on the web interface). However, I built a C-extension for Python (I'm using Windows) that handles CTRL-C events in my C++ code (a toy example):

```
static int s_interrupted = 0;

BOOL WINAPI consoleHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType) {

  switch (fdwCtrlType)
  {
  // Handle the CTRL-C signal.
  case CTRL_C_EVENT:
      s_interrupted = 1;
      return TRUE;
  }
}

int main() {
    s_interrupted = 0;
    int output = 1;
    if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(consoleHandler, TRUE)) {
        std::cout<<"ERROR: Could not set control handler"<<std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout<<"Control hanlder installed"<<std::endl;
    }
    int k = 10000;
    while (int i < k) {
        if (s_interrupted == 1) {
            output = -1;
            break;
        }
         output = i
         i = i + 1;
    }
    return output;
}
```

The output of my main program changes depending on the value of `s_interrupted`. In other words, if I don't press CTRL+C, the program will finish the while loop and return an integer. If I press CTRL+C, the while loop will be terminated and return a different integer. I don't expect to see a `KeyboardInterrupt` in my Python terminal.

It works fine, when I call this C extension in the terminal. However, when I do it in a Jupyter notebook, the program behaves as if I never interrupted the kernel. Does Jupyter not send a `SIGINT` when I interrupt the kernel?

Comment: Have you read the [Jupyter messaging documentation](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messaging.html)? Restarting a kernel is just another message from front-end to back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not install signal handlers and `s_signal_handler` is not used. You need to call `signal` function to register your callback.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <signal.h>

::std::atomic<bool> s_interrupted{};

static void signal_handler(int signal)
{
  s_interrupted = true;
}

int main()
{
    ::signal(SIGINT, &::signal_handler);
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code. `s_signal_handler` is not necessary here. I already have `consoleHandler`. What does `::signal()` do?

Comment: @user1691278 `signal` function registers signal handlers so you can actually handle `SIGINT`

Comment: doesn't `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` do the job though?

Comment: @user1691278 It kinda does, but it is a windows specific thing and signal handlers are more portable. And `CTRL+C` is not exactly the same as `SIGINT`

Comment: What is `CTRL+C` then?

Comment: Now I see `forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event` and quits Python. This is not exactly what I wanted: I wanted the program to return a different integer when I send `CTRL+C`.

Comment: @user1691278 There is no way to hit Ctrl+C fast enough to interrupt this loop unless you intentionally slow program execution somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `consoleHandler()` here, because *there is no console*. The IPython kernel is a 'headless' child process that executes code on request, directed by the Jupyter frontend.

To interrupt a running IPython kernel, the Jupyter front-end uses the `SIGINT` signal. It does so on both POSIX and on Windows; on Windows Jupyter uses additional infrastructure built around [`CreateEventA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventa), [`SetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setevent) and [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) to achieve the same result as a POSIX `os.killpg(PID, SIGINT)` call; a separate thread polls for the event and triggers a `SIGINT` signal in the main thread.

Note that the IPython kernel explicitly restores the Python default signal handler for every message it handles. See the [`ipykernel.kernelbase.Kernel` implementations for the `pre_` and `post_handler_hook` methods](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/34ca17011c1e79f65290b88f1deb18ac03e142af/ipykernel/kernelbase.py#L280-L287):

```
 self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
```

and

```
 signal(SIGINT, self.saved_sigint_handler)
```

These two hooks are executed before and after every message handler (so for [every message sent by the frontend to the kernel process](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messaging.html), including [execute messages](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messaging.html#execute)).

It is `signal.default_int_handler` that raises `KeyboardInterrupt` in the main Python thread. If your code must detect interrupts, it will need to register its own `signal` handler each time IPython executes a cell.

As a side note: a standalone interactive Python interpreter doesn't use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` to detect keyboard interrupts *either*; the only place that is used in the Python source code is in the [`py` launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher), and only then to silence control codes with a handler that returns `TRUE`, always. Instead, Python relies on [Windows sending the `SIGINT` signal to all attached console processes for the active console window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals).